# Inspector interface serializer

Tags: c#, gui, serialization, unity3d

I've written some code that allows Unity3D's inspector to display fields that conform to an interface. Unity has some quirks about their inspector, so as a preface they are listed here:

- If you add a `[Serializable]` attribute to a class, Unity's Inspector will attempt to show all public fields inside that class.
- Any class extending `Monobehaviour` automatically has the `[Serializable]` attribute
- Unity's inspector will attempt to display any private field with the `[SerializeField]` attribute.
- Unity's inspector *will not* attempt to display generic types or interfaces, with the exception of `List<T>`, which is hard-coded.
- Unity's inspector *will not* attempt to display properties. A common workaround is to have a private backing field for your property with `[SerializeField]` attached. Setters won't be called on the value set in the inspector. It's typically only set pre-compilation time, although a developer can modify values in the inspector during runtime. Currently it is acceptable to me to only take the initial value, although if anybody has a simple and efficient way to update successfully, I'd be happy to hear it.
- Unity has a `PropertyDrawer` class you can extend to control how a type is displayed in the inspector. The `PropertyDrawer` for an interface or generic type will be ignored.

**The code**

*UnityInterfaceHelper.cs*

```
[Serializable]
public class UnityInterfaceHelperBase
{
    [Tooltip("The component that is of the type required.")]
    [SerializeField]
    public Component target;
}

[Serializable]
public class UnityInterfaceHelper<TInterface> where TInterface : class
{
    public TInterface TargetAsInterface
    {
        get
        {
            if (targetAsInterface == null)
            {
                targetAsInterface = target as TInterface;
            }
            return targetAsInterface;
        }

        set
        {
            if (targetAsInterface != value)
            {
                targetAsInterface = value;
                if (value as Component != null)
                {
                    target = targetAsInterface as Component;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    [Tooltip("The component that is of the type required.")]
    [SerializeField]
    private Component target;

    private TInterface targetAsInterface;

    public static implicit operator UnityInterfaceHelper<TInterface>(UnityInterfaceHelperBase b)
    {
        return new UnityInterfaceHelper<TInterface>()
        {
            target = b.target
        };
    }

    public static implicit operator UnityInterfaceHelperBase(UnityInterfaceHelper<TInterface> b)
    {
        return new UnityInterfaceHelperBase()
            {
                target = b.target
            };
    }
}
```

*UnityInterfaceHelperPropertyDrawer.cs*

```
[CustomPropertyDrawer(typeof(UnityInterfaceHelperBase), true)]
public class UnityInterfaceHelperPropertyDrawer : PropertyDrawer
{
    public override void OnGUI(Rect position, SerializedProperty property, GUIContent label)
    {
        label = EditorGUI.BeginProperty(position, label, property);

            position = EditorGUI.PrefixLabel(position, GUIUtility.GetControlID(FocusType.Passive), label);
            EditorGUI.PropertyField(position, property.FindPropertyRelative("target"), GUIContent.none);

        EditorGUI.EndProperty();
    }
}
```

**Typical usage**

```
[SerializeField]
private UnityInterfaceHelperBase itemComparable;

public IComparable ItemComparable
{
    get { return ((UnityInterfaceHelper<IComparable>)itemComparable).TargetAsInterface; }
    set { ((UnityInterfaceHelper<IComparable>)landedComparable).TargetAsInterface = value; }
}

public void CompareItems()
{
    if(ItemComparable.CompareTo("Hello") == 0)
    {
        Debug.Log("Hello world!");
    }
}
```

I'm looking to reduce the amount of code I have to repeat for every property, it's already down quite a way, but I'm hoping to make it as simple as possible, but any other comments on the code are welcome too.

Comment: If there's no other idea about this, maybe do some code generation, possibly [via](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/T4TextTemplateTransformationToolkitCodeGenerationBestKeptVisualStudioSecret.aspx) [T4](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb126445.aspx)?

Comment: Check out the Full Inspector for Unity by Sient. No need to re-invent the wheel. I believe there is a trial version as well. The source code might also be available if you purchase it. http://jacobdufault.github.io/fullinspector/

Comment: I like it, but it has a number of issues that I think are dealbreakers: 1) Having to make all classes inherit from their own Monobehaviour subclass, that's a lot of renaming, 2) Having to use a custom serialization toolkit to get non-Moonobehaviour types serialized. I do like their extra features on top, but they're not what I'm looking for (and not free either).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Possible bug:

If you get the value, `targetAsInterface` is initialized. One can then set the value to something that is not a `Component`. Like `null`.

If you then get the value again, you'll get the old value of `target` recasted to `TInterface`. Seems to me that this violates what `get` and `set` are supposed to do.

Comment: Looks like you're correct. Perhaps I need to implement `PropertyChanged` notifications or something similar.